# android: Updating a contact using batch method

Tags: java, android, contactscontract

I'm using below code to updating a contact:

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,  
                    new String[] {Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                              new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        Builder builder= ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " +  
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " +  
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{contactId,  
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,  
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber);
            ops.add(builder.build());
        try {
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.i("SirwanError", e.getMessage());
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                Log.i("SirwanError", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Program works without any error, but contacts don't get updated.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem this way:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, contactType);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);


ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " +  
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " +  
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{contactId,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,  
                                String.valueOf(contactType)}).withValues(contentValues).build());


try
{
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} 

catch (Exception e)
{

            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
}
```